# Unit testing help

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Given the the following method what and how can I test?

```
public void DoSomething
{
   Get Db record 
   Update Db the record
   Log History in Db
   Send an email notification
}
```

Comment: You are doing too much in that method. If you stick to the Single Responsibility Principle (part of S.O.L.I.D) then you'll find testing much easier because you are only testing one thing at a time. You'll also find your code much easier to maintain too.

Comment: And if you look into the rest of SOLID you'll also find a whole heap of other things that make unit testing much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I agree with the other posters that this method is doing too much. I personally would have it do only the Db stuff, then have my application layer log the action and send the email. That said, to unit test this method, I would do the following (in C#):

Firstly, give the class that method exists in a constructor like this:

```
public MyClass(
    IRepository repository,
    ILoggingService loggingService,
    INotificationClient notificationClient)
```

...where the `IRepository` is an interface something like this:

```
interface IRepository
{
    Db GetDbRecord();
    void UpdateDbRecord(Db record);
}
```

...the `ILoggingService` is something like this:

```
interface ILoggingService
{
   void LogInformation(string information);
}
```

...and the `INotificationClient` is something like this:

```
interface INotificationClient
{
    void SendNotification(Db record);
}
```

In the constructor body, assign the passed-in parameters to private, readonly fields in `MyClass`.

Next, in the `DoSomething` method, get the `Db` record from the `IRepository`, update it and save it back to the `IRepository`. Log the history using the `ILoggingService`, then call `SendNotification()` on the `INotificationClient`.

Finally, in your unit tests, use a mocking framework (like Moq) to mock up one of each of the interfaces. Pass the mocked objects into a new instance of `MyClass`, call `DoSomething()`, then verify that your mocked `IRepository` has been asked to update the `Db` object, your mocked `ILoggingService` has been asked to log a message, and your mocked `INotificationClient` has been asked to `SendNotification()`. That is to say:

```
Db record = new Db();

var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();
mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetDbRecord()).Returns(record);

var mockLoggingService = new Mock<ILoggingService>();

var mockNotificationClient = new Mock<INotificationClient>();

new MyClass(
    mockRepository.Object,
    mockLoggingService.Object,
    mockNotificationClient.Object).DoSomething();

// NUnit syntax:
Assert.That(record["ExpectedUpdatedField"], Is.EqualTo("ExpectedUpdatedValue"));

mockRepository.Verify(r => r.UpdateDbRecord(record), Times.Exactly(1));

mockLoggingService.Verify(ls => ls.LogInformation(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));

mockNotificationClient.Verify(nc => nc.SendNotification(record), Time.Exactly(1));
```

In the running system you would inject proper implementations of `MyClass`' dependencies, and you've then shared the responsibilities amongst more coherent objects.

Bit long-winded, but that's how I'd do it :)

Answer (score 0):

For Unit testing - you are not having a "unit" method. It is doing too many things. Extract out methods for each single job it does and test those methods.

Generally, Unit Tests do not include DB changes etc. so you have to see how you can attack that part. It is going to depend on the framework you use etc. You can mock the database methods and verify you are calling them. Don't go about seeing if the data is added to db etc. That is not Unit testing and you will start to realize that your tests become flaky, slow and cannot be parallelized etc.

Have integration tests / db test for the data part and make sure you rollback any data that you modify. Also make sure that no test is dependent on a change made by some other test.